# Save custom data to custom table error

Tags: magento-1.8, module, error, model

I need to save data to a custom table.

**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Npm_Commission>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Npm_Commission>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_place_after>
                <observers>
                    <npm_commission_model_observer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Npm_Commission_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>calculateCommission</method>
                    </npm_commission_model_observer>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_place_after>
        </events>
        <models>
            <npm_commission>
                <class>Npm_Commission_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>commission_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </npm_commission>
            <commission_mysql4>
                <class>Npm_Commission_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <commission>
                        <table>commission</table>
                    </commission>
                </entities>
            </commission_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <commission_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Npm_Commission</module>
                      <!-- <class>Npm_Commission_Model_Mysql4_Commission</class> -->
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_setup>
            <commission_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_write>
            <commission_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </commission_read>
        </resources>
    </global>
</config>
```

**DATA**

```
$insertData = array(
            'order_id' => $orderId,
            'transaction_id' => $transaction_id,
            'foundation_id' => $foundation_id,
            'mano_admin_fees' => $manoAdminFees,
            'mano_promotion_fees' => $manoPromoFees,
            'paypal_fees' => $payPalFees,
            'foundation_fees' => $foundationFees,
            'created_at' => $created_at
            );
```

**Insert code**

```
$collectionSet = Mage::getModel('commission/commission');
            $collectionSet->setData($insertData)->save();
```

**custom table install script**

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();
$installer->run("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$installer->getTable('commission')};
CREATE TABLE {$installer->getTable('commission')} (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `order_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `foundation_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `mano_admin_fees` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `mano_promotion_fees` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `paypal_fees` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `foundation_fees` decimal(10,2),
  `created_at` datetime,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
");
$installer->endSetup();
```

**I am getting error**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on a non-object in
```

Comment: Did you create model `commission/commission` in Magento? Post module config.xml, and all model files :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
$collectionSet = Mage::getModel('npm_commission/commission');
```

EDIT:

There should be npm too. The problem for me is that Magento don't have proper model config.

```
        <npm_commission_mysql4>
            <class>Npm_Commission_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <commission>
                    <table>commission</table>
                </commission>
            </entities>
        </npm_commission_mysql4>
```

Some links:
http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/04/creating-a-magento-custom-model/
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-5-magento-models-and-orm-basics

Comment: It gives new error                                  Fatal error: Call to a member function beginTransaction() on a non-object in

Comment: I've edited my comment, problem is wrong module configuration for me ;)